# Помогите объединить строки в массиве PHP 7.1

Tags: php, массивы, класс

Помогите разобраться с массивами PHP.

Есть вот такой массив:

```
Array
(
    [TAGS] => Array
        (
            [title] => Тайтл
        )
)
Array
(
    [TAGS] => Array
        (
            [description] => Описание
        )
)
```

Он выводится кодом:

```
public function SetPageProperty($TYPE,$TAGS){
    $arr['TAGS'][$TYPE]=$TAGS;
}
```

Данные в функцию передаются вот так:

```
$APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("title", "Тайтл");
$APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("description", "Описание");
```

Необходимо объединить массивы, что бы получить 1:

```
Array
(
    [TAGS] => Array
        (
            [title] => Тайтл
            [description] => Описание
        )
)
```

---

### PHP - 7.1

Прошу больше конструктива, так как комментарии на подобие "Иди учи PHP", не помогут мне решить данный вопрос.

UPD
Ответы не решили мой вопрос. Массив так же не объединился в один.

Comment: `$arr['TAGS'][$TYPE] = $TAGS;`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как объединить массив PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1013762/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-php)

Comment: Не помогло решить вопрос

Comment: Пишите `Он выводится кодом:` и ниже приводите код который ничего не выводит. Разберитесь, пожалуйста, с тем что же вы действительно делаете.

Comment: Также стоит отметить что вы работаете с Битриксом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class A{

    private $tags = [];

    public function SetPageProperty($TYPE,$TAGS)
    {
        $this->tags['TAGS'][$TYPE]=$TAGS;
    }

    public function getTags()
    {
        return $this->tags;
    }
}

$APPLICATION = new A();
$APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("title", "Тайтл");
$APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("description", "Описание");
$APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("price", 1000);

print_r($APPLICATION->getTags());
```

И Результат:

```
Array
(
    [TAGS] => Array
        (
            [title] => Тайтл
            [description] => Описание
            [price] => 1000
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

$arr['TAGS'][$TYPE]=$TAGS;

Через телефон нельзя нормально описать ответ.
 Вашем коде была перезапись существующего массива

Comment: К сожалению это не решило мою проблему     Array
(
    [TAGS] => Array
        (
            [title] => Тайтл
        )

)
Array
(
    [TAGS] => Array
        (
            [description] => Описание
        )

)

Comment: private $arr = []; public function SetPageProperty($TYPE,$TAGS){
    $this->arr['TAGS']=array($TYPE=>$TAGS);
} public function GetPageProperty(){
    return $this->arr;
}

Comment: Нечего не поменялось

Comment: Изменил ответ. Вызывать GetPageProperty после SetPageProperty. Вызов var_dump($this->GetPageProperty ());

Comment: В данном случае var_dump($APPLICATION->GetPageProperty ());

Comment: private $arr = []; public function SetPageProperty($TYPE,$TAGS){ $this->arr['TAGS'][$TYPE]=$TAGS; } public function GetPageProperty(){ return $this->arr; }

Comment: Большое при большое спасибо. Всё робит